# hyperledger explorer walletstore path

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer, hyperledger-explorer

When I start to run hyperledger explorer I get this below error. After a search I found that I need to give a path to walletstore path. But I couldn't find where the walletstore path.

```
docker-compose.yaml file 
    volumes:
      - ./config.json:/opt/explorer/app/platform/fabric/config.json
      - ./connection-profile:/opt/explorer/app/platform/fabric/connection-profile
      - ./organizations:/tmp/crypto
      - walletstore:/opt/explorer/wallet
```

```
[2022-05-23T12:31:18.513] [ERROR] FabricGateway - Failed to create wallet, please check the configuration, and valid file paths: {
explorer.mynetwork.com      |   "errno": -2,
explorer.mynetwork.com      |   "syscall": "open",
explorer.mynetwork.com      |   "code": "ENOENT",
explorer.mynetwork.com      |   "path": "/tmp/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/User1@org1.example.com/msp/signcerts/cert.pem"
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, check the read and write permission of the folder path "/tmp/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/"

Comment: I found the solution the problem was inside test-network.json signedCert path. ``` "organizations": {
  "Org1MSP": {
   "mspid": "Org1MSP",
   "adminPrivateKey": {
    "path": "/tmp/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/keystore/priv_sk"
   },
   "peers": ["peer0.org1.example.com"],
   "signedCert": {
    "path": "/tmp/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/signcerts/Admin@org1.example.com-cert.pem"
   }
  }
 }```

Comment: @newUser would you please elaborate? I am in the same issue

Comment: "adminPrivateKey": {
    "path": "/tmp/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/keystore/ORG1_MSPKEY"
   },
You should add ORG1_MSPKEY there

Comment: solved the issue by changing the path to use /tmp/crypto.... i was using my local path

Comment: yes need to rename all